# Where is HibernateTestMixin located in Grails 3?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-3.0

I am trying to upgrade a Grails 2.5.1 application to Grails 3.0.5. When I try to run the tests I get a compiler error

```
/Users/xxx/dev/xxx/src/test/groovy/y/xxx/z/PricingSpec.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class grails.test.mixin.hibernate.HibernateTestMixin
@ line 5, column 1.
import grails.test.mixin.hibernate.HibernateTestMixin
```

It seems that `grails-plugin-testing` does not include that Mixin. Can anyone tell me what dependency I am missing?

**EDIT** Same goes for `grails.test.mixin.gorm.Domain`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`HibernateTestMixin Basics`](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/testing.html).

You would need this dependency in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:4.0.4.RELEASE'
}
```

You might not have noticed it but these mixin were already had been moved to `grails-data-mapping` in Grails 2.4.* apps

If you look closely in `BuildConfig.groovy` of a newly created Grails 2.4.* or 2.5.*, one would see the same dependency.

Comment: Thank you so much. I absolutely missed that.

Comment: Note that for Grails 3.1 (or 3.0.x when using GORM 5), you need a `5.0.x.RELEASE` version. I think it is best to not specify the version, so you get the same version as the other `grails-datastore` plugins